# Is function sleep() active or passive?

Tags: c, operating-system, system, sleep, system-calls

Is function sleep() in C an active wait or passive wait?

Since it stops the thread running, is it always checking if the time has passed like:

```
while(1){
//need to wake?
}
```

Or a passive like:

```
alarm(sec);

pause(); // wait for the alarm and sleeping?
```

The system is unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sleep` is **not** a standard C library function.

If your platform has it, it almost certainly will make a call to the operating system to suspend the thread (that is, in your notation, *passive*).

It will not adopt a `while(1){}`-type idiom as that will unnecessarily burn the CPU.

Comment: what is the correct terminology? If I think about locks I would say busy waiting vs sleep.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to the implementation of the [sleep()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) function.

One is to use the `alarm()` function to schedule a **SIGALRM** signal and then suspend the calling thread waiting for that signal. The other is to implement an independent facility.

Function `sleep()` is in  passive wait in unix.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` is a [standard POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html):

> **The `sleep()` function shall cause the calling thread to be suspended
>   from execution** until either the number of realtime seconds specified
>   by the argument seconds has elapsed or a signal is delivered to the
>   calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function
>   or to terminate the process. The suspension time may be longer than
>   requested due to the scheduling of other activity by the system.
>
> ...